# How to randomize the post on home page on "Whatever" Theme

Tags: php, post, html

Make the posts randomized on home page from functions.php in child theme
(I used DIVI but it should generally work)

Answer (score 0):

Writing this in functions.php inside the child the should do the job.

Using comparison of links because it seems that all the modules are set to callback archive templates so is_home and the rest malfunction.

```
global $post;
$homeBSD = get_home_url();
$thisBSD = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
function random_posts( $query ) {

if ( $homeBSD == $thisBSD ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'random_posts' );
```